# OpenGL web game: C++ with Java vs pure Java?

Tags: c++, java

I'm going to write **browser online game**, **not MMO**, but something like a lot of Flash game. But with OpenGL rendering, because Flash is using CPU for rendering.

What are advantages of pure Java or c++ with Java that only create window.

My requirements are:

- **good performance** - low overhead when calling OpenGL functions
- short code( if possible ) - so, Java is fully object oriented language, which can require usage of object for each called OpenGL function
- basic **portability - Linux, Mac, Windows** - multiple builds for each platform aren't problem
- little communication with server for saves, top score,... not multiplayer - may be slow
- game should be downloadable

Comment: just have a feeling it'll have benefits if you use pure java, I think  it's because pure java can run on any platform but if you try combining those languages c++ binaries would prevent cross-platform features

Comment: For clarity, are we talking web in browser, or web as in multiplayer downloadable binaries? @Gajet out of interest, how does C++ limit cross platform features? Most libraries are X-platform.

Comment: Have you thought of using WebGL?

Comment: Just FYI: The [upcoming release](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/features/molehill.html) of the Flash player will use the GPU and provide hardware accelerated 3D and 2D rendering.

Comment: @The Communist duck: since when you are writeing a code with java the jar files compiler generates can run on any platform but you have to build seperate binaries for each platform when using c++ and there are always some libraries which have small diffrences in diffrent platforms, which is why cross-platform c++ projects have some specific platform programmers.

Comment: @zacharmarz: i haven't. It's extension for JavaScript and i like compiled languages.

Comment: @Gajet the amount of platform specific code is usually covered by your windowing library if you have one. @Miro, is this meant to be in browser or not?

Comment: @The Communist Dock: not only that, any driver specific thing (window, audio, networking, ..., usualy all the thing that the game engine handles) are platform dependent only creating window doesn't make c++ code platform independent, and if he tries to create binaries with c++ he has to have all target platforms to compile his code. but with java I think you can compile only on windows and expect the results from same jar file running on a mac.

Comment: @Gajet Ok, replace 'windowing library' with 'libraries'. It is not difficult to get a few different libraries together - or just get a game engine.

Comment: -1, what exactly are you asking here? Advantages in what areas? Which one do you prefer? You haven't given any real requirements, and even if you had (i.e. "performance", it really wouldn't be answerable since there is so much more to a program than the language itself. Why do you need or want to use java at all?

Comment: @Tetrad: ok, i've specified it better. Java is required, because i haven't found way to run c++ application in browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Java, don't bother with anything else. If it becomes necessary to start augmenting the program with C++ bolt-ons, you can do so later once you've proven it to be to true.

Until then, you'll be able to build a perfectly excellent game in Java that meets all your requirements and has the advantage of being significantly easier to build and deploy since you won't have to deal with the hassle that is C++'s lack of *binary* portability.

If you're into it, it looks like it's also possible to use a [developer preview version of Flash](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplatformruntimes_incubator.html) to get the hardware accelerated features bummzack mentions.

Comment: if you use just java, other than controls, would it make an easy convert to android?

Comment: I don't know too much about Android, somebody else is probably better suited to respond to that.

Comment: The game itself (game logic etc.) should be trivial to move to Android, but the UI components will probably need a bit of rewriting to the Android APIs. For example, the Andoid OpenGL ES library is a bit different from what you get in LWJGL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing it for the browser, C++ is not an option; you would have to use Java. Alternately, look at [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).